# Can't add items to Magento cart

Tags: html, magento, checkout, cart

When ever I add an item to my cart I get a 500 server error http://www.supremerattanfurniture.co.uk/

Comment: Welcome to SO please read how to post a right question http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking Thanks

Comment: Please have a look on this great debugging answer and comment back: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Solution

If you're getting a blank page then it seems to be a PHP error. The steps to debug it would be: 1. Make sure error reporting is turned on, write temporarily:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the beginning of of index.php file.
2. change theme to a different one. I'd suspect error in
app/design/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart.phtml
3. disable local and community modules.

Second Solution

This is a PHP Memory Limit Issues. Its happens to me. Even if 256 MB will not work so go for 500m

Go to magento Root and .htaccess and change the current value to as per this and then Flush the cache and check your shopping cart and it will work.

```
## adjust memory limit
php_value memory_limit 500M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```